# Partial wine packages won't remove completely

Tags: wine, 32-bit

I've looked at a few answers for this problem `apt-get` commands to remove clean and purge packages. I've also tried removing the leftover packages by name but that does not work either.

Only one of the remaining packages is functional, and that is browse `C:\` drive. I tried reinstalling Wine, but it failed do to unmet dependencies.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

open up nautilus (file manager), make sure you're in your home directory.

Use `CTRL H` to see hidden files. Scroll down to a file called `.wine` and delete that folder and it's contents. This will remove your wine 'home drive'.

In terminal (if you haven't got it already): `sudo apt-get install synaptic`, which will install an advanced version of the USC.
Once installed, open it up and in the search box type `wine`. Scroll down the list and tick `remove` for every `wine` item that has been ticked. Click apply, which will then completely remove the selected components.

Note: you must only remove anything that has wine in its name only.

From here you should be able to reinstall wine again, if required.

Hope that helps.